# How to get token transfer history of an account on Corda

Tags: corda

I'm using [Token SDK](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk) and [Account Library](https://github.com/corda/accounts). There is no docs that talks about token transfer history by account. Please help with any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I followed this example (github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/flow-db) to create a custom table that stores my token transactions (i.e. issue, transfer, redeem); so every time I do one of those commands, I insert a record in my custom table (which has columns such as from-account, to-account, quantity, timestamp, etc...).